# Spliting a UIImage in half issue in iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, xcode6, uiimage

I have a view with lots of buttons and need to take a print out of it, currently I convert my view into an image and just directly print it and it works fine, now according to a requirement I have to split the image vertically into two halves. I need this only for iPad. Below is my code on how I do this.

```
        UIImage *myImage = [Utilities changeViewToImage:_mainView withBounds:viewSize];
        NSLog(@"%f-%f", myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height); //409.000000-563.000000 (same for both normal iPad and retina)
        CGImageRef tmpImgRef = myImage.CGImage;
        CGImageRef topImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height/2));
        topImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImgRef];
        CGImageRelease(topImgRef);

        CGImageRef bottomImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, myImage.size.height / 2.0,  myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height / 2.0));
        bottomImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bottomImgRef];
        CGImageRelease(bottomImgRef);
```

This works perfectly fine on iPad 7.1 and I get half of my image in topImage and rest in bottomImage. But when I run it on iPad air or retina, I only get 1/4th of the topImage, I had to change the frame setting for topimage by doubling the width and same height to get the result like `CGImageRef topImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, myImage.size.width, myImage.size.height/2));`

But the image size is again large and I will have to again shrink it, so currently I will have to check if its normal iPad or retina and adjust accordingly, is there a better way to do this so that it would work both on normal iPad and retina/air?

Comment: You could use `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]` to do it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this using the image.scale option while creating frame and then resizing the resulting image according to my need.

```
    CGImageRef tmpImgRef = myImage.CGImage;
    CGImageRef topImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, 0, myImage.size.width*myImage.scale, (myImage.size.height*myImage.scale)/2));
    topImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:topImgRef];
    CGImageRelease(topImgRef);

    CGImageRef bottomImgRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(tmpImgRef, CGRectMake(0, (myImage.size.height*myImage.scale) / 2.0,  myImage.size.width*myImage.scale, (myImage.size.height*myImage.scale) / 2.0));
    bottomImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:bottomImgRef];
    CGImageRelease(bottomImgRef);
```